# MGTwitter is not working

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter, ios6, mgtwitterengine

I don't want `default twitter` to open because it should be compatible with `ios < 5` also .

I've used `MGTwitterEngine`. But it doesn't post tweets. Before few days it was working fine with ios5 too. But now it's not working. I think twitter `demo url is depreceated` , or not supported with ios5 & 6. **What could be the reason?** while posting something to twitter the request gets failed & I'm gettiing following error :

**`Error Domain=HTTP Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 404.)`**

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifications...
1. Change the TWTTER_DOMAIN in the MGTwitterEngine.m line 40 (pat posted).
2. Chenge the OAuthConsumer.h remove all OAuthconsumer strings.
3. Chenge the HTTP url with SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m line 65~67, add the api string before twtter.com

Comment: thanks yun..I got what I wanted by just changing the twitter_domain!

Answer (score 26):

Twitter deprecated API version 1 url.
In **MGTwitterEngine.h** line 40 change

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"twitter.com"
```

to

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"api.twitter.com/1"
```

More info https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803

Comment: Getting same error after made above changes.in Twitter sharing

Comment: This is actually in MGTwitterEngine.m file (not in header).

Answer (score 0):

### Version 1 of the API is now deprecated. This document may describe an outdated version of the API. Please move to [Version 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) of the API as soon as possible.

Go through this document.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/direct_messages/new

Point to be noted

- Api format should me json
- Api version v1.1
- sender and receiver should follow each other.

Example Request

**POST** : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json
**POST Data** : text=hello&screen_name=rajneesh071